# bin/sh: 1: visqol: not found

Tags: python, bazel

When I execute my code it shows me error as below, I don't know what is this `visqol_find.py:33 ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: visqol: not found` meaning, and I pretty sure that `visqol_value` and `visqol_threshold` are both defined as float because the program is working fine with my professor.

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 and python is 3.6.12.

This is code for `visqol_value`

```
def visqol(reference_file: str, degraded_file: str, visqol_model_path: str = __visqol_model_path__) -> float:
    status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput("visqol --reference_file {} --degraded_file {} --similarity_to_quality_model {} --use_speech_mode".format(reference_file, degraded_file, visqol_model_path))
    if status != 0:
        for _line_ in output.split('\n'):
            logger.error(_line_)
        raise RuntimeError("VISQOL Command-Line Error.")
    visqol_score = None
    for output_line in output.split("\n"):
        if output_line.startswith('MOS-LQO:'):
            visqol_score = float(output_line.split()[1])
    if visqol_score is not None:
        return visqol_score
    raise RuntimeError("VISQOL Command-Line Error.")
```

```
        visqol_value = visqol(clip_file, adversarial_path)
        if visqol_value < visqol_threshold:
            right_bound = potential_delta
            if _delete_failed_wav_:  # delete
                for _file_ in glob.glob(adversarial_path[:-4] + "*"):
                    os.remove(_file_)
            logger.debug("VISQOL Exceeds for music clip '{}' with 'delta_db={}'.".format(clip_name, potential_delta))
            continue
```

This is code for `visqol_threshold`

```
def get_visqol_threshold(formant_weight: Union[list, np.ndarray], phoneme_num: int) -> float:
    formant_weight = np.array(formant_weight)
    _alpha = 0.95  # The higher the value of _alpha and _beta is, the faster the visqol threshold decreases.
    _beta = 8.0
    _theta = 10.0
    o = np.sum(formant_weight != 0.)
    if o == 5:
        base = 1.7
    elif o == 4:
        base = 1.8
    elif o == 3:
        base = 2.2
    else:
        if formant_weight[1] < 0.75:
            base = 2.3
        else:
            base = 2.25

    return base * (_alpha ** (max((phoneme_num - _theta) / _beta, 0.)))
```

I would like to know how I should fix it?
Since I am running this project in a virtual python environment, is it possible that it is because I put visqol in the wrong place, and if so, where should I download visqol to

The program works but keeps looping with these two error messages until I manually terminate it

```
(.venv) dunliu@dun:~/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master$ python3 2022gen_100song_bing_001.py 
2022-11-13 17:23:58 2022gen_100song_bing_001.py:433 WARNING: The destination folder './task/weather1/generate/0490c9606d8e333e' will be removed. Please backup this folder, and then enter 'Y' to continue, or others to exit...
y
2022-11-13 17:24:01 2022gen_100song_bing_001.py:437 INFO: The destination folder './task/weather1/generate/0490c9606d8e333e' was removed.
2022-11-13 17:24:01 2022gen_100song_bing_001.py:325 INFO: ********************    Start Binary-search Generation.    ********************
2022-11-13 17:24:01 visqol_find.py:34 ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: visqol: not found
2022-11-13 17:24:01 utils.py:361 ERROR: program exit!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 357, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/visqol_find.py", line 35, in visqol
    raise RuntimeError("VISQOL Command-Line Error.")
RuntimeError: VISQOL Command-Line Error.
2022-11-13 17:24:01 utils.py:361 ERROR: program exit!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 357, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "2022gen_100song_bing_001.py", line 257, in generate
    if visqol_value < visqol_threshold:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
2022-11-13 17:24:01 visqol_find.py:34 ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: visqol: not found
2022-11-13 17:24:01 utils.py:361 ERROR: program exit!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 357, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/visqol_find.py", line 35, in visqol
    raise RuntimeError("VISQOL Command-Line Error.")
RuntimeError: VISQOL Command-Line Error.
2022-11-13 17:24:01 utils.py:361 ERROR: program exit!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 357, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "2022gen_100song_bing_001.py", line 257, in generate
    if visqol_value < visqol_threshold:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

after I terminate it, it shows

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "2022gen_100song_bing_001.py", line 448, in <module>
    binary_generation_task()
  File "2022gen_100song_bing_001.py", line 444, in binary_generation_task
    binary_generation(params)
  File "2022gen_100song_bing_001.py", line 395, in binary_generation
    generate(_wake_up_analysis_file_, _command_analysis_file_, _clip_file_, output_folder, params)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 359, in wrapper
    raise _err
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 357, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "2022gen_100song_bing_001.py", line 251, in generate
    adversarial_path = gen_by_command(delta_db_list, bandwidth_list, command_analysis_file, clip_file, output_folder, adversarial_filename, params)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 359, in wrapper
    raise _err
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/utils.py", line 357, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/formant_processor.py", line 688, in gen_by_command
    command_filter_list = generate_filter(command_formant_list, m_sample_rate, bandwidth, min_fre, max_fre, filter_order, reserved_fre_gap_ratio)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/formant_processor.py", line 356, in generate_filter
    signal.butter(f_order, [_s_fre_, _e_fre_], btype='band', output='sos')
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py", line 2894, in butter
    output=output, ftype='butter', fs=fs)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py", line 2407, in iirfilter
    return zpk2sos(z, p, k)
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py", line 1447, in zpk2sos
    z = np.concatenate(_cplxreal(z))
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py", line 887, in _cplxreal
    z = atleast_1d(z)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in atleast_1d
  File "/home/dunliu/research/Phantom-of-Formants-master/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 25, in atleast_1d
    @array_function_dispatch(_atleast_1d_dispatcher)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't specify the visqol's absolute path in the shell script, your code couldn't call the visqol.

I suggest specifying the visqol's absolute path.

try the command below in your shell ( Or your terminal ).

```
which visqol
```

If the path exist, then replace "visqol" in the code below with the result above.

```
status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput("visqol --reference_file {} --degraded_file {} --similarity_to_quality_model {} --use_speech_mode".format(reference_file, degraded_file, visqol_model_path))
```

It looks like "~~ getstatusoutput("/absolute/path/visqol --reference_file ~~"

If not, install "visqol" via the code below in your shell (OR terminal) and try the solution above.

```
# install bazel to build visqol
# https://bazel.build/install/ubuntu

sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg
sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade

# install numpy python library.
# https://github.com/google/visqol#linuxmac-build-instructions

pip install numpy

# download source code and build visqol
# https://github.com/google/visqol#linuxmac-build-instructions

git clone https://github.com/google/visqol.git
cd visqol
bazel build :visqol -c opt
```

Comment: I can't download visqol by ‘apt install visqol’ or 'sudo apt install visqol' either in the terminal or in the virtual environment. The package doesn't seem to be downloadable from the command line

Comment: You have to build it from the github repo. ( https://github.com/google/visqol ). instruction is ( https://github.com/google/visqol#build ).

Comment: I changed the answer. I thought it was just a package that can be installed via apt.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is from `/bin/sh`. That means you are expecting your (bash/dash/other) shell to execute a Python script which isn't going to work.

You need to either put a Python shebang as the first line of your script, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
...
... rest of script
```

then make it executable with:

```
chmod +x YOURSCRIPT.PY
```

and run with:

```
./YOURSCRIPT.PY
```

Or, you need to start it like this, specifically with the Python interpreter:

```
python3 YOURSCRIPT.PY
```

Comment: Which file should I put this line of code in? the one I want to execute or the one that will be called like this'visqol_find.py'?

Comment: You can put it at the top of any/all python scripts, unless you particularly enjoy typing `python3 thisscript.py` and `python3 thatscript.py`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, still shows same error : (

Comment: Ok, please click `edit` under your question and show exactly how you run your script along with the complete error message,

Comment: Okay, you should be able to see it now